# Is it possible to have custom domain for Azure App Service with private endpoint

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I am working on configuring Azure App Service with private endpoint according to MS documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/networking/private-endpoint.

It works for default domain (azurewebsites.net) under VPN (Point-To-Site). However, for custom domain I am getting the following error it does not work for custom domain.

[image]

The custom domain has the public DNS record with CNAME pointed to default domain (azurewebsites.net).

Is it possible to handle custom domains with private endpoint?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, It is possible to have a custom domain for Azure App Service with Private Endpoint.

Iam able to access custom domain even with VPN.

***Check the below steps to configure an app with custom domain and access it.***

- Initially I have deployed a Web App with sample code to Azuer App Service.
- Create a new DNS Zone and create a record set with type `CNAME`.

[image]

- Initially your record set looks like below.
  [image]
- Add the Custom Domain in the Azure Web App.

[image]

- Click on `Add Binding` => Select the existing certificate.

[image]

- After adding the custom domain, the record set in the DNS Zone alias value gets updated with the deployed URL.

[image]

- Add the private Endpoint.
  [image]
- In your Azure App, make sure the `Unmatched rule action` is set to `Allow` in the `Networking` => `Access Restrictions` section.

[image]

***Web App Default URL:***
[image]

***Custom Domain:***
[image]

Comment: You still have public access enabled on your app service, thus connection will be public and not private. The issue is with private DNS zones, this is not supported in App Service.

Answer (score 0):

The only solution could be to use public DNS temporarily for custom domain verification.
See more here:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1162930/how-to-set-app-service-custom-domain-for-private-e
- https://blog.aelterman.com/2022/01/10/azure-app-service-using-a-custom-domain-name-in-a-private-namespace/